# How to fix slider in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a shopping site i am using slider for the ads but when slider's photo change, page refreshing itself.
this is the code i used for the slider.

```
 <div style="width: 1200px; height: 250px; margin-left:300px;>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="4000"></asp:Timer>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
```

and this is code behind the file

```
public partial class Kullanıcı : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public static int sayac = 0;
    public void sld()
    {
        if (sayac == 1)
        {
            Label3.Text = "<img src= 'Slider/22.jpg' width='1200px' height='350px'/>";
        }
        else if (sayac == 2)
        {
            Label3.Text = "<img src= 'Slider/23.jpg' width='1200px' height='350px'/>";
        }
        else if (sayac == 3)
        {
            Label3.Text = "<img src= 'Slider/24.jpg' width='1200px' height='350px'/>";
        }
        else if (sayac == 4)
        {
            Label3.Text = "<img src= 'Slider/4.jpg' width='1200px' height='350px'/>";
        }
        else if (sayac == 5)
        {
            Label3.Text = "<img src= 'Slider/5.jpg' width='1200px' height='350px'/>";
        }
    }
```

and this is page_load section

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sayac++;
        if (sayac == 6)
        {
            sayac = 1;
        }
        sld();

    }
```

Comment: it would make a lot more sense to implement this using JavaScript

Comment: i m not sure but i think this has got a recursive effect, while you call sld() and still do condition check

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the advice but i have to do this  with c#

Comment: why exactly? that seem pretty arbitrary. It's a really obvious use case for Javascript.